# trying to run a python script from a php script: returns a pid but doesn't execute

Tags: php, python, linux, bash

I am trying to execute a python script in the background and get a pid from a php script which is called by a button click. The issue here is that the PID doesn't exist and the task of the python script is not done. Im not sure what is happening. I have tested the python script using terminal, it works like a charm.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo 'Starting the mapping process';
            echo exec('python frist_script.py > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!');
            //echo exec('ls > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!;');
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The python script just executes a `ls` and writes the output to a file. The code for the python script as follows.

```
import os
import datetime, time
import sys
import argparse
import psutil
import glob
import select

os.system('ls >output_files.dat')
```

**Note:** This is not the final script, but a test script to confirm that my python script call works fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

PS: Output of `ls -al`

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 acs      www-data     262 May 18 16:31 execute.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data     147 May 18 16:17 frist_script.py
```

I have also tried shell_exec();

EDIT: I tried to run a simple shell script, but that doesn't get executed as well but Shell commands work.

**UPDATE:** The  python script or the shell script works when executed from terminal `php execute.php` but doesn't work when running from the web-server.

Comment: Did you try adding a shebang to your python script and executing it like above?

Comment: @Will_Panda: yes.. I did try adding the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python`, but  it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: ... but doesn't work when running from the web-server.
>   Does your Server **have** PHP support?

Create a new script or replace your `os.system(...` with this:

```
import subprocess
try:
    # os.system('ls >output_files.dat')
    lsoutput = subprocess.check_output('ls', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)  
    print('ls output:', lsoutput)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
     print("CalledProcessError:", e)
```

**Call this script from your `php script`**.

---

Change from

```
 echo exec('python frist_script.py > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!');
```

to

```
 echo exec('python frist_script.py >> /tmp/php_exec 2>&1');
```

to see **any** error message.

Comment: It doesn't throw any error message when changed to `echo exec('python frist_script.py');`.

Comment: Yep tried it.. The /tmp/php_exec file gets created but is empty. I assume that means there are no errors. I have also updated the question. The python script executes when the php script is called from the terminal `php execute.php`

Comment: @user37: Updated my Answer, please retry.